# Android - Fragment is null after Picture Intent (REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE)

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-fragments, null

I have an app which has a `PagerAdapter` with a few `Fragments`.
From the main `Activity`, I start a `REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE intent`, it works ok, when it ends it calls `onActivityResult()`.
In `onActivityResult()`, I have simple code:

```
m_PagerAdapter.GetTheFrag().DoStuff(..., ...);
```

Where `m_PagerAdapter` = derived from a `PagerAdapter`,

`GetTheFrag()` = // returns the derived Fragment object, which wasn't null before starting the Intent. This is the problem,

DoStuff() ==> never gets called, because `m_PagerAdapter.GetTheFrag()` is null .

The weird thing is that sometimes it does work and sometimes not, doesn't matter what picture quality or any capture related properties.

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

// In PagerAdapter
public MyFrag GetTheFrag() {
    return m_MyFrag;
}

// In PagerAdapter
private View getViewByID(Integer integerID) {
    switch (integerID) {
        case R.layout.my_frag:
            if (m_MyFrag == null) {
                m_MyFrag = new MyFrag(m_MainActivity);
            }
            return m_MyFrag.GetMyFragView();
    }
    return null;
}
}

// In MyFrag
public View GetMyFragView() {
    return m_ThisView;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the class that is the implementation of `m_PagerAdapter`, particularly the `GetTheFrag()` method and any data members that it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your process was terminated while the camera app was in the foreground. A fresh process was created for you as part of returning control to your app after the camera finishes. A fresh activity will have been created, along with fresh fragments. However, whatever `m_MyFrag` is, it is not being filled in by your code when this occurs, and so it is `null`.

You will be encountering the same sort of problem if the user leaves your app (e.g., via HOME), Android terminates your process, but then the user returns to your app within 30 minutes or so of having left. So, while you happen to be experiencing it as part of launching a third-party camera app, the same problem will occur elsewhere.

Comment: So how can I overcome this ?
Some sort of an onResume() changing ?

Comment: @MikoDiko: "So how can I overcome this ?" -- I have no idea. I do not know what `MyFrag` is or why a `PagerAdapter` would be trying to reference it. One solution would be to put something in the saved instance state `Bundle` that allows you to re-retrieve `m_MyFrag` when your activity is re-created.

Comment: It's simply:
public class MyFrag extends Fragment {..}

Comment: @MikoDiko: Well, if that fragment is being managed by a `FragmentManager`, it will be automatically recreated when the activity is recreated. But your `m_MyFrag` data member will not be. In `onCreate()` of your activity (or fragment or wherever `m_MyFrag` lives), you can call `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` on the `FragmentManager` to get the fragment back, so you can fill in `m_MyFrag`.

Comment: I'm not using a FragmentManager, but a ViewPager with a PagerAdapter as the adapter.
This is such a weird problem, for months it didn't happen, now sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't, even though I always return as quickly as I can to the app, after taking the pictures.

Comment: @MikoDiko: "I'm not using a FragmentManager" -- then I have no idea what you are doing and cannot help you further, sorry.